# convert NSString to int16_t and insert them inside core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

hello what i am trying to do is to taking a NSString value  from UITextField and convert this value into int16_t to save it inside my core data after many hour of googling some of the stack people said that core data could not accept primitive data type such as **int** **Boolean** etc... and should receive object type such as **NSNumber** **NSInteger** etc...  here is my code:

```
                 CoreData *coreDat  = [CoreData defaultStack];

    numberEntity *entry =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NumberEntity" inManagedObjectContext:coreDat.managedObjectContext]
    ;





    [entry setNumber:(NSNumber *)self.numberTextField.text];
```

and here is the entity class:

**numberEntity.m**

```
        #import "numberEntity.h"
        @implementation numberEntity
        @dynamic  number;
        @end
```

**numberEntity.h**

```
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        @interface numberEntity : NSObject
        @property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber *number;
        @end
```

and for my core data is  integer 16

*i could not post the image due to my low reputation i am so sorry also i am still new to stackoverflow.com*

but after running this code i got this exception :

> Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "number"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = __NSCFString; value = 1.

hope you will help me forget to mention that i am still newbie in IOS development and i came from android development

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to parse the text into a number. e.g. `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.numberTextField.text intValue]]`. That can then be used as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line [entry setNumber:(NSNumber *)self.numberTextField.text]; to [entry setNumber:@([self.numberTextField.text intValue])]; .Hope its working.